# Objective C to Swift translation issue [Facebook SDK]

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift

So I'm translating my Objective C project which uses Facebook SDK. Here's my code:

```
 FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];         
 connection.errorBehavior = FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorReconnectSession
        | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorAlertUser
        | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorRetry;
```

If I got it right after a lot of searching, there is no need to use bitwise on Swift and I should use [ , ] syntax instead, so:

```
 var connection: FBRequestConnection = FBRequestConnection()
 connection.errorBehavior = 
     [FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorReconnectSession,
           FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorAlertUser, 
                FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorRetry]
```

But now I'm getting an error:

> Cannot assign a value of type '[FBRequestConnectionErrorBehavior]' to
>   a value of type 'FBRequestConnectionErrorBehavior'

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check your `Swift` syntax, please.

Comment: use like `[FBRequestConnectionErrorBehavior.ReconnectSession,FBRequestConnectionErrorBehavior.AlertUser,FBRequestConnectionErrorBehavior.Retry]`

Comment: @El Captain Still doesn't work

Comment: Please upgrade your Facebook SDK. This no longer applies to Facebook iOS SDK version 4.7.0